# How to fix parameter errors in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

This is my controller:

```
public function admin_debit()
{
    $date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $trans_type=2;
    $amount=$this->input->post('amount'); 
    $total_amount = array_sum($amount);
    $json=json_encode($_POST);  
    $user=$this->session->userdata('sess_pt_userid');
    $data=array(
                   'dated_on'=>$date,
                   'amount'=>$total_amount, 
                   'userid'=>$user,
                    'purpose'=>$json,
                    'trans_type'=>$trans_type
                 );
 $response = $this->Petty_model->debit_insert($data);
 //add flash data 
         if($response)
         {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Cash Debited Successfully ');
           redirect('Petty_controller/debitview');
         }
     else
       {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something worng. Error!!');
         redirect('Petty_controller/debitview');
       }      
}
```

Here an error occurred in my code:

> array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.

I get an another error which says:

> Column 'amount' cannot be null

Comment: Please check the value of amount from where you are fetching it from.

Comment: array_sum requires parameter as an array, here a variable is passed to. please read : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: May be the "amount" input box in your html was't an array. please check it is <input type="text" name="amount[]" /> like this?

Comment: it should be like this : $amount[] = $this->input->post('amount'); Or  $amount in form should be an array

Comment: public function debit()
{
 if(($this->session->userdata('sess_pt_usertype'))==1)
   {
    redirect('Petty_controller/admin_debit');
   }
   else {
    redirect('Petty_controller/user_debit');
   }
}

Comment: first in your function `var_dump($this->input->post('amount'));` and let us know what the response is...

Answer (score 1):

If your amount like '1,2,3' this then you need set this in array

```
$amount = '1,2,3';

$amount = explode(",",$amount);

$total_amount = array_sum($amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $amount=$this->input->post('amount'); 
 $total_amount = array_sum($amount);
```

here the `$amount` is null because from the input it receives nothing. and `array_sum` requires an array to be operated upon. instead it gets null, thus the exception occures

Answer (score 1):

just check if post data of amount is array

```
$total_amount=0;
if($this->input->post('amount') && is_array($this->input->post('amount')){
 $total_amount = array_sum($this->input->post('amount'));
}
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$trans_type=2;
$json=json_encode($_POST);  
$user=$this->session->userdata('sess_pt_userid');
$data=array(
               'dated_on'=>$date,
               'amount'=>$total_amount, 
               'userid'=>$user,
                'purpose'=>$json,
                'trans_type'=>$trans_type
             );
$response = $this->Petty_model->debit_insert($data);
```